# How to merge two csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to merge two csvs file in python.

I can merge two csvs file in normal way by following code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil
from natsort import natsorted

dir = r"./data/"
#if not os.path.exists(dir):
#    os.mkdir(dir)
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in natsorted(glob.glob('./data/*.{}'.format(extension)))]
#srt_files = natsorted(all_filenames)
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv( os.path.join(dir , "train.csv"), index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

But I have to merge them in different way now.

So I want my new csv in this format

```
|header | header |...| header|
-------------------------------
|1st row from 1st row of csv A|

|2nd row from 1st row of csv B|

|3rd row from 2nd row of csv A|

|4th row from 2nd row of csv B|
```

I want to make a new csv from csv A and csv B in which new csv's rows will contain rows in above format. like csv A, csv B, and again csv A, csv B, ......

Can I get some hint or help to make new csv in this format?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps [Concatenate dataframes alternating rows with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44152439/15497888)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I solved the problem. It was easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the index after `concat`

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]).sort_index()
```

then reset the index as well,

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```